# Is there any way to hide "edit layout" button from detail page by apex?

Tags: apex, api, soap-api, permissions

I have a scenario where I need to hide the edit layout button on particular for any user by the apex. We can use visualforce page once it loaded to check the condition we hide the 'edit layout' but I couldn't get anything around that how it can be done?

Comment: Only users with Customize Application will see this option. Are you trying to hide this function from System Administrators?

Comment: I wanted to manage that permission by apex

Comment: No, that's managed by system permissions.

Answer (score 2):

As [sfdxfox commented](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/304891/is-there-any-way-to-hide-edit-layout-button-from-detail-page-by-apex#comment455072_304891), the availability of the edit layout button is currently controlled by the "Customize Application" System Permission.

Something you could try is taking the permission away from the profiles of all the users who might need it hidden. Then use a [PermissionSetAssignment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_permissionsetassignment.htm) and a **permission set** with "Customize Application" enabled to selectively grant it again.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you need a `Custom Permission` here.

Comment: @AdrianLarson You don't think the custom `Permission Set` to selectively grant the "Customize Application" system permission to the user is required?

Comment: I guess all permissions sets are "custom". Is it just a problem with the wording? I'm not aware of another way to selectively regrant the required permission to a subset of users.
Well, short of changing their profile or assigning them to a group.

Comment: There are two separate but similarly named features in `Custom Permissions` and `Permission Sets`. To use the phrase "custom permission sets" is therefore confusing.

Comment: @AdrianLarson OK. I've tried to clarify that the permission set is required for use with the permission set assignment.